# How to send network location (not GPS) to android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, location

I want to test my app on an emulated device that does not have a GPS, and just have network location. I have created the hardware profile for a device without GPS.

How can I send a LAT/LONG location to this emulator using network location?
The only option I see on the emulator is to send the location as GPS data point.

- Note
  this is different from [How to emulate GPS location in the Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator). I want the network location, not GPS location. they are from different location providers although they return the same information.

**background**

There are some platform changes affecting API 21 coming on 15 Oct 2016, and I would like to test the user experience for my app due to the changes. This include testing on emulated devices

- with network location without GPS
- with GPS without network location

According to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Permission, we now need to include either of the following uses-feature into the manifest

> android.hardware.location.network or android.hardware.location.gps

my app requires either one of the two, so I included the following

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"  />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="false" />
```

The following questions contains some information regarding the changes:

[When do I need android.hardware.location.gps and android.hardware.location.network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603270/when-do-i-need-android-hardware-location-gps-and-android-hardware-location-netwo) and

[Android : create simulator without GPS hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609676/android-create-simulator-without-gps-hardware)

Comment: @yong.k different question. I do not want to emulate a GPS location. I want to emulate a network location. They are different location providers.

Comment: Also network delivers lot/lan, thus it's a duplicate. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775257/android-location-providers-gps-or-network-provider

Comment: @tuergeist, unfortunately, the question you list did not say how to emulate the positions  with network location.  GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER triggers different part of my codes (basically some visual cues on the UI). I want to test the parts relating to NETWORK_PROVIDER.

Comment: @AngelKoh, I'm not an expert, but for me it looks like that what you want is impossible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424564/activating-network-location-provider-in-the-android-emulator

Comment: Any update on this question?